# Java ee7 websockets server endpoint not working

Tags: java, maven, websocket

Here's my server's code

```
package local.xx.mavenws;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnError;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

@ApplicationScoped
@ServerEndpoint("/")
public class Server {

    private final ArrayList<Session> sessions;

    public Server() {
        this.sessions = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        this.sessions.add(session);
        this.echo("Client connected!");
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session) {
        this.sessions.remove(session);
        this.echo("Client disconnected!");
    }

    @OnError
    public void onError(Throwable error) {
        this.echo("Error occured!");
        this.echo(error.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message, Session session) {
        try {
            message = "[" + this.currentDate() + "] " + message;
            this.echo(message);
            for( Session sess : this.sessions ) {
                sess.getBasicRemote().sendText(message);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    private void echo(String info) {
        System.out.println(info);
    }
    private String currentDate() {
        String dateArray[] = (new DateTime()).toString().split("T");
        String date = dateArray[0] + " " + (dateArray[1].split("\\.")[0]);
        return date;
    }
}
```

I want it to send received message to all the users connected. The problem is, it treats every connection individually like each one of them had it's own instance of the server. When I connect in two browser windows, messages show separately. Does anybody have any ideas on this?

Comment: Maybe try to make a Singleton class Message and put / retrieve your message from that class.

Comment: What do you mean by `each one of them had it's own instance of the server`? When two users are connected what's the size your `sessions`?

Comment: @JFPicard I don't think it'd change anything... The point is @karthik that my `sessions` size is always 1. I print it in server console after receiving message. But server is mutual for all users, because their messages log in the same console. Strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got this working! The solution is that the `sessions` variable must be static and I had to call it always by `Server` scope, not `this`. That implicates the fact that, despite there's a new instance of `Server` created for every user connected, the variable is mutual for everyone.